# Flutter change notifier

Tags: android, flutter, websocket, software-design

Hi I am quite new with flutter and finding it very hard to manage states with websocket triggers. I have been able to establish websocket connection between a microcontroller and flutter. So what I have been trying to do is to fire an event when a certain message is arrived in flutter. For that I have set up a model with ChangeNotifier extention. I have used context.watch() to track the changes. When I change the data manually from within the build fucntion where the data is being watched it works and the widget tree rebuilds but when the data is manipulated outside of the build function for example via websocket events the widget does not rebuild. I also have a continuous timer based set state rebuild which gets triggered every minute. Every time the widget rebuilds I can see that the data present in my model class is stored correctly with every Websocket event but it did not trigger the rebuild. I dont understand what I am doing wrong. My code is spread across multiple files so I can show this at the moment.

I tried the best I could to explain the problem let me know if you want more explanation. I am soo tired searching around for the answer for days :-(

EDIT:3 (in the actual code there is another page with is used to call the `ClockSettingPage` it is a `bottomTabBarPage`) I have update the code below to represent the actual code better.

EDIT 4: SOLVED :-)

```
// MAIN
void main() => runApp(
    //USED MULTI PROVIDE BECAUSE THERE ARE MORE THAN ONE IN ACTUAL CODE//
      MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => WebsocketsProvider()),
        ],
        child: MyApp(),
      ),
    );


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const MaterialColor white = const MaterialColor(

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    routes: {
      TabsScreenPage.routeName: (context) => TabsScreenPage(),
      ClockSettingsPage.routeName: (context) => ClockSettingsPage(),
      },
    );
  }
}



// MY MODEL
class WebsocketsProvider extends ChangeNotifier {

  static final IOWebSocketChannel channel =
      new IOWebSocketChannel.connect('ws://192.168.1.17:81/');

  int _wsEventTrack;
  int get wsEventTrack => _wsEventTrack;
  set wsEventTrack(value) => _wsEventTrack = value;

  void incrementEvent()
  {
    wsEventTrack = wsEventTrack + 1;
    notifyListeners();    // IMPORTANT
  }

  void subscribeToStream() 
  {
  StreamSubscription subscription = channel.stream.listen(
  (payload) {
    Map tempResponse =
      jsonDecode(payload.toString()) as Map<Object, Object>;
    if (tempResponse['echo'] == 'echo') {

      //ws connected and right data received
      print('triggered');
      incrementEvent();
    }
  }
}


///////////////////////
//tab screen page
///////////////////////

class TabsScreenPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/tabsScreenPage';

  @override
  _TabsScreenPageState createState() => _TabsScreenPageState();
}

class _TabsScreenPageState extends State<TabsScreenPage> {

/* HERE I ACTUALLY SUBSCRIBE TO THE WEBSOCKET STREAM */
WebsocketsProvider().subscribeToStream();

void _selectPage(int index) {
    
    setState(() {
      _selectedPageIndes = index;
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

        body: _pages[_selectedPageIndes]['page'],
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          currentIndex: _selectedPageIndes,
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.access_time),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
          ],
          onTap: _selectPage,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////
///  Class where the data is processed and required
// this needs to rebuild when there is a change in the
//  WEBSOCKETPROVIDER CLASS's DATA
///////////////////////////////////////////////////

class ClockSettingsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/clockSettingsPage';
  @override
  _ClockSettingsPageState createState() => _ClockSettingsPageState();
}

class _ClockSettingsPageState extends State<ClockSettingsPage> {
  
  // SETUP OF THE TIMER REBUILDS IS IN THE INIT STATE//

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    final notifier = context.watch<WebsocketsProvider>();
  return Scaffold(
    body: Container(
      child: InkWell(
        /* THE PROBLEM LIES HERE WHEN THE INKWELL IS TAPPED 
THE DATA INSIDE THE WEBSOCKETS PROVIDER CLASS IS INCREMENTED
 AND THE WIDGET GETS REBUILD BUT WHEN THE DATA IS INCREMENTED
 IN THE WEBSOCKET PROVIDER CLASS INTERNALLY DUE TO WEBSOCKET
 STREAM THIS WIDGET DOES NOT GETS REBUILD ALTHOUGH I KNOW THAT
 THE DATA IS BEING STORE WITH THE WEBSOCKET EVENTS BECAUSE IN
 THE INIT OF THIS CLASS THERE IS A CONTINUOUS REBUILD EVERY
 MINUTE AND WHENEVER THE WIDGET REBUILDS THE MISSING DATA GETS
 CORRECTED */
            onTap: notifier.incrementEvent,
            child: Text(notifier.wsEventTrack.toString()),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: The only thing I can see that's wrong here is the fact that you're referencing a private property from your `ClockSettingsPageState`. You should be referencing `notifier.wsEventTrack` instead of `notifier._wsEventTrack`. Also, I would give your _wsEventTrack a default value of 0 like this: `int _wsEventTrack = 0;`. Besides that, I really don't see anything else you're doing that could be causing it to not update correctly.

Comment: Another optimization would be to replace all of this:
`int _wsEventTrack;
  int get wsEventTrack => _wsEventTrack;
  set wsEventTrack(value) => _wsEventTrack = value;`

with this:
`int wsEventTrack = 0;`

Comment: Thanks for looking it up but I accidenty added the `_wsEventTrack` it is `wsEventTrack` only in the actual code. Even with the `notifier.wsEventTrack` the widget does not update. One thing that is different in the above code and the actual code is that the `ClockSettingsPage` class is in the `bottomTabNavigatorState`. Do you think that should cause any trouble?

Comment: It all depends on your implementation. I think you should update the code above with all relevant code you would like reviewed.

Comment: Sure I have added the missing page. This `BottomTabPage` loads before the ClockSettingsPage and is responsible to call the ClockSettingPage in it body. Hope that make it a bit more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The Issue

With `ChangeNotifier` you need to make sure you're referencing the same instance of the class that you're updating and listening to.

### So Far So Good

You're creating an instance of the `WebsocketsProvider` class (which extends `ChangeNofitier`) in your `MultiProvider` widget and providing it as a `ChangeNotifierProvider`. Then, you're listening to that instance inside of your `ClockSettingsPage`. Everything is correct up to this point.

### The Mismatch

Inside of your `_TabsScreenPageState`, you're creating a brand new instance of the `WebsocketsProvider` class and listening to that stream. This doesn't work because the `ClockSettingsPage` is listening to changes on a completely different instance of that class.

### The Update

Override the `initState` method to your `_TabsScreenPageState` and call super like usual. Then, subscribe to the instance of the class created by `Provider` like this:

```dart
context.read<WebsocketsProvider>().subscribeToStream();
```

if the syntax above doesn't work you can do it the old-fashioned way:

```dart
Provider.of<WebsocketsProvider>(context, listen: false).subscribeToStream();
```

p.s. I didn't see you disposing of your streams anywhere. If you're not doing that please look into how to dispose streams in Dart. This will prevent memory leaks in your application.

Comment: Thankyou for going over my code and giving me a solution. It worked as expected and now it is causing the rebuild of the `ClockSettingsPage` whenever the data is changed in the provider. I have been trying to do this from last 2 days with no luck. I am not experienced at the moment hence I still dont completely understand why it did not work earlier. Could you suggest me some literature or topics to go over to be a better developer.